# Mysqli fetch array with prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am in the process of making my mysql queries prepared in an attempt to increase security, however I have a problem when I attempt to fetch the results of a prepared statement. I can successfully fetch one row of data however I have had no success fetching an array of data. All of the research I have done has provided examples that either don't work or are way too complicated.

**My Current Code**

```
if ($stmt = $dbc->prepare("SELECT city FROM users WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1")) {
$stmt->bind_param('i', $id);  // Bind id to parameter.
$stmt->execute();    // Execute the prepared query.
$stmt->store_result();

 // get variables from result.
$stmt->bind_result($city);
$stmt->fetch();
}
```

This is my current code which only returns one result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well lets see, 
First of all you LIMIT your select query to 1 result, thats one thing why its only returning 1 result,
 Second, you aren't using a while loop to loop through your results, try this:

```
$stmt = $dbc->prepare("SELECT city FROM users WHERE id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($city);
while($stmt->fetch()){
    echo $city;
}
```

***But keep in mind that your query is probably only going to return 1 value since ID is probably UNIQUE***

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the other areas which I needed to take into consideration and modify accordingly.